# Core Java Swing software setup

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I have a Core Java Swing project that I am using with MySQL database.

How to create software setup and how to use MySQL database client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used install4j recently for similar purpose. You can refer [this](http://cbsecsnip.in/tutorial/how-to-make-setup-file-of-java-program/how-to-make-setup-file-of-java-program.php) tutorial for in detail steps.

Comment: But How use mysql database in client system . Otherwise there also my sql setup installation and mysql queries(table) run required

Comment: How To make setup manually witout sofware